# Theano TensorType error

Tags: python-2.7, theano, nolearn

When I am using nolearn to implement multi-label classification, I got this error:

> 'Bad input argument to theano function with name "/Users/lm/Documents/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nolearn/lasagne/base.p‌​y:391"
>   at index 1(0-based)', 'TensorType(float32, matrix) cannot store a
>   value of dtype int64 without risking loss of precision. If you do not
>   mind this loss, you can: 1) explicitly cast your data to float32, or
>   2) set "allow_input_downcast=True" when calling "function".',
>   array([[0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 1],

Answer (score 6):

As told in the error message, you need to convert your input and output to the appropriate type (if you do not fear losing precision).

```
input = input.astype(np.float32)
output = output.astype(np.float32)
```

should work

Note: even if you do this, the error might remain if you have a `BatchIterator` which transforms your data (and  by inadvertance uses `float64` again). The solution is the same: inside the `BatchIterator`, cast the data to `float32` right before returning it.

Answer (score 0):

In my case all I did was change the `floatX` flag (under `[global]`) to on the .theanorc file from :

```
[global]
floatX = float64
```

to:

```
[global]
floatX = float32
```

*Notice that the 64 at the end was replaced by the 32.*